# Alter transform angle using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, css, matrix, rotation, transform

A `.rot` div has `transform:rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg)`.
I want to increase or decrease the rotate x or y according to the 4 buttons `.x-inc, .x-dec, .y-inc, .y-dec` but when i did `rot.css("transform")` it gave me matrix form not string or deg . Now how will i alter those rotations based on clicked button?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a variety of ways, but here is a simple fiddle that shows you three - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V5wLJ/1/)

1. Add a 45degree class
2. Call the transform directly
3. Create a function and pass a number

JS

```
$('.clickme1').on('click', function(){
     $('.rotateme').addClass( 'rotatemenow' );
});

$('.clickme2').on('click', function(){
    $('.rotateme').css( 'transform', 'rotate(45deg)');
});

$('.45degrees').on('click', function(){
    spinabox(45);
});

$('.60degrees').on('click', function(){
    spinabox(60);
});

function spinabox (angle)
{
    $('.rotateme').css( 'transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
}
```